# How can I use react-zoom-pan-pinch to allow users to view all of a chart that changes size based on user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zooming, panning

I've designed and built an interactive Org Chart that allows users to view business organizations in a hierarchical format. By default only the first row below the root node of the chart is visible, but users can click to expand the chart further, thereby changing the size of the chart. Users can also drag and drop nodes to simulate a reorganization of the business.

I'm currently using [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page) to allow users to zoom and pan the chart. It works very well when the org chart has not been expanded too much, but becomes problematic at larger chart scales.

The problem is that the organizations being represented by the chart are very broad in comparison to their depth, meaning a fully expanded chart is a horizontal rectangle, not a square. [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page) will only allow me to zoom out to the maximum vertical extent of the chart, meaning users can't view a fully expanded organization without scrolling from side to side. This is not an acceptable behavior.

This is for work, so I cannot post code without violating numerous agreements. Instead I have linked to the [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page) documentation and will go over what I have tried changing.

The first place I looked was the TransformWrapper Props section of the documentation.

There I found the `inititalScale`, `minScale`, and `maxScale` props.

I can set the `initialScale` prop to a value of less than 1, and obtain something close to the result I want at first. Setting it to 0.5 results in the chart being zoomed out further than normally possible, but when I zoom in to a value of 1 I am unable to zoom back out. This was expected, as the `minScale` prop was still set to 1.

Having checked that the props indeed work, I went ahead and set `minScale` to 0.5, assuming I would be able to zoom back out to the initial view seen when `initialScale` is set to 0.5. This seemed like it should work, but it did not. Even with the `minScale` prop set to 0.5, I am unable to zoom back out after zooming in to a value of 1. This is very strange to me, as the acceptance of 0.5 as the `initialScale` prop and subsequent rendering of the chart indicates that values below 1 are acceptable.

I am now messing around with the rest of the props listed in the documentation, but have yet to achieve the desired result (infinite zoomout).

I believe the root of the issue is that [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page) is meant for images, not things that change size and aspect ratio, but it is a good package and I would prefer to keep using it.

What are the settings I should be using to allow infinite zoom out?

Comment: While it is not acceptable as part of the question, I would also accept recommendations for other pan/zoom packages. This one seems widely used and otherwise works well, but I'm willing to switch. I could probably just write the code myself, but that seems like a reinventing the wheel sort of thing to do, and I don't have that much extra time.

Comment: I discovered the issue, at least partially. The `minScale` value in the react dev tools still shows up as 1. Some of the other props work and have the same values in the dev tools as they do in the code, but others are also not showing the correct values in the dev tools. It's very strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered the answer to my own question. It turns out the `minScale`, `maxScale`, and other props were not being passed to the component properly. Once they are passed properly the package works very well. Here's my explanation/fix

The documentation suggests doing this:

```
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";

class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TransformWrapper
        initialScale={1}
        minScale={0.5}
        maxScale={7}
        initialPositionX={200}
        initialPositionY={100}
      >
        {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, ...rest }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="tools">
              <button onClick={() => zoomIn()}>+</button>
              <button onClick={() => zoomOut()}>-</button>
              <button onClick={() => resetTransform()}>x</button>
            </div>
            <TransformComponent>
              <img src="image.jpg" alt="test" />
              <div>Example text</div>
            </TransformComponent>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </TransformWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

The above doesn't work, and the `minScale` and `maxScale` props aren't passed to the component. If you open the React dev tools in your browser and go to `TransformWrapper`, you'll see the default values of 1 for `minScale` and 8 for `maxScale`, not the values you entered in your code.

You can solve the problem by creating an object:

```
  const transformOptions = {
    initialScale: 1,
    minScale: 0.5,
    maxScale: 2
  }
```

Then setting an `options` prop inside the TransformWrapper component equal to the object, like so:

```
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";

class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TransformWrapper
        initialScale={1}
        options={transformOptions}
        initialPositionX={200}
        initialPositionY={100}
      >
        {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, ...rest }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="tools">
              <button onClick={() => zoomIn()}>+</button>
              <button onClick={() => zoomOut()}>-</button>
              <button onClick={() => resetTransform()}>x</button>
            </div>
            <TransformComponent>
              <img src="image.jpg" alt="test" />
              <div>Example text</div>
            </TransformComponent>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </TransformWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

The same thing applies to pan, wheel, and zoom options. They don't work if set directly in the component as suggested by the documentation, but do work if you create objects like I did above.